# Flutter firestore compund queries is not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from Firestore using 2 where clauses but it is not working as expected. here is what I am trying

```
      final userQuery = _usersCollection
          .where('mode', isEqualTo: UserMode.Available.index); //user mode is an enum

      final validUsersQuery = await userQuery
          .where('dateJoined', isLessThanOrEqualTo: maxDate)
          .get();

      final docs =
          validUsersQuery.docs; // empty list
```

when I try to execute each query, it returns some data, however, when I combine them, I get empty result. I also tried this but it didn't work for me

```
      final userQuery = await _usersCollection
          .where('mode', isEqualTo: UserMode.Available.index).where('dateJoined', 
           isLessThanOrEqualTo: maxDate).get();

      final docs =
          userQuery.docs; // empty list
```

Can anyone help me in finding the issue?

Comment: print the error you get, you should see a link from firebase, open it..It'll allow you to create a composite index.

Comment: I don’t get any error. It just returns nothing. So is it required to create an index to use compound queries?

Comment: Yes, Index is required for making compound queries. If you don't see any link in the console to create index then create it by going through firebase console -> firebase database -> index -> Add index -> {Collection ID => users, Field indexed => mode and dateJoined(Ascending/Descending), QueryScope => Collection}. It'll work.

Comment: it works just fine when I created the index.. Thank you.